# iOS Simulator not connecting to web service

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am developing a Cordova project on XCode.

am using Cordova v5.4.1, Xcode v7.2 and iOS simulator v9.2.

The app is building and deploying successfully on the emulator but the REST web services are not being consumed. I am able to view the JSON response from the web service in the emulator's Safari browser, but the app does not show the same.

I have enabled "allow HTTP services" in the developer settings and also tried restarting the emulator and Xcode, but nothing helps. I have also added these lines to the config.xml.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
```

How can this issue be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're getting blocked by iOS 9 ATS (App Transport Security)?

To test if it could be the case, try this on your Mac, using Terminal.app:

```
nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://api.your-server.com
```

If ATS would allow connecting to https://api.your-server.com, you should see this, in the first block of the response:

```
Default ATS Secure Connection
---
ATS Default Connection
Result : PASS
---
```

Anything else means ATS would block the HTTP(S) requests from going through.

To resolve this, you can either fix the issue at the root (use HTTPS with TLS 1.2, SHA256 or better, and forward secrecy), which is the recommended solution, but not always possible, or define an exception for your server to be allowed in your `App-Info.plist` file. Example:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>api.your-server.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

More info on ATS, and the values you can use to define exceptions: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

If all else fails, you can try to use this Cordova plugin:
https://github.com/robertklein/cordova-ios-security
But I don't recommend it, as it completely disables ATS, which is a pretty-bad-idea™.